# MATLAB: Checkpointing in ode function

Tags: matlab, cluster-computing, ode, hpc, differential-equations

After optimizing my code, my ode solver, ode45, takes a long time to finish. But the server only allows me to have a walltime of 24 hours. I cannot request longer walltime. I know how to do checkpointing for `for` loop. But How to do checkpointing for `ode45`, efficiently?

Comment: You can store the last state of your system to use it as a starting point for new integration.

Comment: Btw, such a long integration time is suspicous. May be your problem is stiff?

Comment: @AVK can you tell me how to store the last state of system to use it as a starting point for new integration. they are large systems involving matrix so i cannot shorten it lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An integration interval can be divided into parts. For example,

```
[t1,x1] = ode45(f,[0 1],x0); % integrate from 0 to 1
save('data.mat'); % save workspace to file
% now you can turn off your computer
load('data.mat'); % load workspace from file
last = x1(end,:); % obtain the last state (the last row of x1)
[t2,x2] = ode45(f,[1 2],last); % integrate from 1 to 2
t = [t1;t2]; % concatenate results
x = [x1;x2];
```

is equivalent to

```
[t,x] = ode45(f,[0 2],x0); % integrate from 0 to 2
```

So you can integrate over the first part of the interval and save results, next time you can continue integrating from the last point, etc.

Comment: `t1 = [0 1]` `t2 = [1 2]`. Is there an overlap in the value 1? Is this a problem in ODE?

Comment: Yes, it is. If this is a problem, the last two lines should be modified as follows: `t=[t1(1:end-1);t2];  x=[x1(1:end-1,:);x2]`

Comment: after `save('data.mat');`, i turn off the computer. But doesn't it when I reopen my computer I rerun the program I have to start running `[t1,x1] = ode45(f,[0 1],x0);` again? How can I jump to `load('data.mat');` after I reopen my computer?

Comment: There are many ways to continue the integration from the previous last state. You can, for example, start the integration from `t1(end)` after loading `data.mat` : `[t2,x2] = ode45(f,[t1(end) t1(end)+1],last);`. Or you can just have several m-files in your program